# SQLAlchamy Database Construction & Reuse

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

there's something I'm struggling to understand with SQLAlchamy from it's documentation and tutorials.

I see how to autoload classes from a DB table, and I see how to design a class and create from it (declaratively or using the mapper()) a table that is added to the DB.

My question is *how does one write code that both creates the table (e.g. on first run) and then reuses it*?

I don't want to have to create the database with one tool or one piece of code and have separate code to use the database.

Thanks in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create_all()` does not do anything if a table exists already, so just call it as soon as you set up your engine or connection.

(Note that if you *change* your table schema, `create_all()` will *not* update it! So you still need "another program" to do that.)

This is the usual pattern:

```
def createEngine(metadata, dsn, **args):
    engine  = create_engine(dsn, **args)
    metadata.create_all(engine)
    return engine

def doStuff(engine):
    res = engine.execute('select * from mytable')
    # etc etc

def main():
    engine = createEngine(metadata, 'sqlite:///:memory:')
    doStuff(engine)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks -- I guess I was looking for a solution to a non-existent problem. What's the best practice solution, auto-loading or defining the classes explicitly? The former would seem to guarantee that the DB and the objects match, but the latter would specify the objects in the code instead of 'by magic'.

Comment: If your application "owns" the database (i.e., it was created for it), then make the table structure explicit in the code. If the application is merely using an existing database, then by all means autoload. Note that in either case there is still no guarantee that the table structure will match your application's expectations. Your app can break in either scenario if the schema is different enough from what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're perhaps over-thinking the situation. If you want to create the database afresh, you normally just call `Base.metadata.create_all()` or equivalent, and if you don't want to do that, you don't call it.

You could try calling it every time and handling the exception if it goes wrong, assuming that the database is already set up.

Or you could try querying for a certain table and if that fails, call `create_all()` to put everything in place.

Every other part of your app should work in the same way whether you perform the db creation or not.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sence... there isn't a problem to fix in the first place!